# Firebase firebase-web.js missing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase

I installed angular firebase using node.js however the firebase-web.js file is missing. I have searched for this file and cannot find it. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: What **exactly** did you install? What does your `package.json` file look like?

Comment: Can you please share commands which you used to install firebase? Did you tried npm install firebase --save ??

Answer (score -2):

[image]

After that, you can see the `firebase-web.js` file.

Comment: the question is asked for web setup for firebase with angular not android. this answer can not help.